# How to leave space, go to next line , underline or make characters bold in knife.fromHtml() ? \n, \t, \r nothing is working

Tags: java, android, html, editor, knife

String x = this is my \n sentence;

knife.fromHtml(x);

When I use this sentence, it's not displayed in a new line

Answer (score 0):

this is duplicate answer but wrote here for you .

```
String sBooks = "Books on Chennai:\n ....";
```

> Replace: "\n" with "< br>" :

```
sBooks = sBooks.replace("\n", "<br>");
```

Example using a TextView:

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(sBooks));
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace all your `"/n"` with `"<br>"`:

```
x = x.replace("\n", "<br>");
```